# EDT value not updating IN label X++

Tags: axapta, x++

In the following chunk of code I have a label described as following:

```
"Today is your birthday %1!  Company x wishes that all your dreams come true!"
```

And the next piece of code:

```
public void init()  
{   
       UserId  curUser  = curUserId();  
       SysCompanyUserInfo sysCompanyUserInfo;   
       VendAccount emplName = SysCompanyUserInfo.VendAccount;
       super();    
       if (curUser == SysCompanyUserInfo.UserId)    
       {        
            GreetingMessage.text(strfmt("@NET4183", emplName));      
            pause;    
       } 
 }
```

The problem is that the  emplName does not update within the label itself.
Any idea why?
Thank you!

Comment: @eyllanesc: gotta give some beers to someone one day to teach me how to properly format the questions :)

Comment: Hi, Without selecting any record in SysCompanyUserInfo , how are you expecting value in SysCompanyUserInfo.VendAccount ? Also not sure how you are getting value in SysCompanyUserInfo.UserId for displaying the GreetingMessage text.

Comment: The info do not show before the `pause` is acknowledged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in `sysCompanyUserInfo` you never select a record for this table.

You need this (or other `select * from sysCompanyUserInfo where...`):

```
SysCompanyUserInfo sysCompanyUserInfo = SysCompanyUserInfo::find(curUserId());
```

Try this:

```
public void init(){   

       UserId  curUser  = curUserId();  
       SysCompanyUserInfo sysCompanyUserInfo = SysCompanyUserInfo::find(curUserId()); 
       VendAccount emplName = SysCompanyUserInfo.VendAccount;

       super();    

       if(curUser == SysCompanyUserInfo.UserId){        
            GreetingMessage.text(strfmt("@NET4183", emplName));      
            pause;    
       } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks ! :)

It work excellent like this also :

> public void init()
>
>{
>    UserId              curUser = curUserId();
>    SysCompanyUserInfo  sysCompanyUserInfo;
>   UserInfo            userInfo;
>   //VendAccount     emplName = userinfo::find.VendAccount;
>  ;
>
>  super();
>
>   select firstonly userinfo
>        where userinfo.id == curUser;
>
>   if (userinfo)
>  {     // info(userinfo.name);
>       GreetingMessage.text(strfmt("@NET4183", userinfo.name));
>  }
> }

Comment: You can comment SysCompanyUserInfo sysCompanyUserInfo; line then. Also as a best practice always remove commented code before releasing.